# Hierarchical master-detail app with xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, master-detail

I'm searching any tutorial or explication how to add a "level" in a table-view.

I'm using XCode 4.3.2. I've created a Master-Detail App, and I did all what I should for a working application. But I have only one Level in my table view, and have absolutely no idea how to get a second level.

I searched a lot in Google and in the Apple documentation, but I haven't found anything..

My wish is to have the list, when you click on an object of the list, you go to the second level with a new list, and when you click on an object of the second list, it changes the Detail View.

Comment: What do you mean by "adding a level"? Do you mean going to the next tableview with new data, or do you mean a new section? E.g. as with the Contacts app using A B C D ect.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you mean is going to the next view controller. 
What you should do is use the delegate method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
([Link to doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3adidSelectRowAtIndexPath%3a))

Here you can create a new tableViewController, e.g.

```
UITableViewController *newTable = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newTable animated:YES];
```

However, what you want to do (I guess) is send data to it which is should show. So, in your newTable tableviewcontroller you should create a new init method which allows you to send in the data you need. For instance an array. The class can then handle that data and show it as you please.

I hope that answered your question.

Comment: Thank you ! It was exactly what I wanted to do, and you helped me a lot ;)

Comment: Your welcome. Do not forget to except it as an answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: This worked for me -- thanks!  The other part of it that took a bit to figure out is how to keep the master view open once you've opened that new table.  The call is in DetalViewController.m within - (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem.  The line: [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; is what causes the master view to hide.